# Loop Crashing Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, crash

i have been having problems with getting my code to run through its conditional loop and stopping. Here is what I have:

```
  Do While True
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).PasteSpecial
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the program to check if one cells isn't empty and if another doesn't have an error in it, if that condition is met, then the program would copy a certain row and re-paste it as just it's values since some of the cells in the row is a formula. For some reason the loop doesn't exit and Excel crashes, am I missing something?

Comment: Put `i = 2` outside the loop above `Do While True`.

Comment: Your value of i never changes. i = i + 1 is fine, but you then reset it to 2 every loop.

Comment: Your loop is exiting when true, so I'd suggest that the criteria are never being met.

Answer (score 3):

the i = 2 should be outside

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While True

If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Copy
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).PasteSpecial
    i = i + 1
Else
    Exit Do
End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points :

1. The i = 2 must be outside the while loop.
2. Don't use *Copy* and *PasteSpecial*. Using the clipboard will give lots of problems later on. Additionally PasteSpecial likes you to be specific with "what" *PasteSpecial* action you're using. Rather assign values directly.

Dim i As Integer, Dataset As Variant

```
i = 2
Do While True
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Not IsError(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        'This seems silly, but it overwrites the cell with its value.
        Dataset = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 22)).Value = Dataset
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
```